# adding current date to file

Tags: python, rename, shapefile

I have this code on PyScripter and I am getting error of SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
txtFileNameWithExt = "ope.shp"
txtFileNameNoExt = f"{os.path.splitext(txtFileNameWithExt)[0]}_{datetime.datetime.now():%Y_%m_%d}"
arcpy.env.workspace = my_Path
arcpy.Rename_management(txtFileNameWithExt,f"{txtFileNameNoExt}.shp")
```

```
Error:
    txtFileNameNoExt = f"{os.path.splitext(txtFileNameWithExt)[0]}_{datetime.datetime.now():%Y_%m_%d}"
                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead and it provides the same output:

```
import os
import datetime
txtFileNameWithExt = "ope.shp"
txtFileNameNoExt = f"{os.path.splitext(txtFileNameWithExt)[0]}_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')}"
```